# Handling pending state for server components during revalidatePath in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I'm starting to work with Next.js 14 and have implemented `revalidatePath` to refetch data after a mutation in my React server components. However, I'm struggling with handling the pending state during this refetching process. I would like to show a spinner on the components that are currently refetching data.

My server components look like this:

```
export default async function ServerComponent() {
  const data = await fetchData()
 
  return <div>{data}</div>
}

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Suspense fallback={<Skeleton />}>
        <ServerComponent/>
      </Suspense>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding you should be able to use the `loading.(jsx|tsx)` file convention to show a loading state for a page or an entire path segment:

```
export default function Loading() {
  // You can add any UI inside Loading, including a Skeleton.
  return <LoadingSkeleton />
}
```

If in the same folder, loading.js will be nested inside layout.js. It will automatically wrap the page.js file and any children below in a  boundary. When calling `revalidatePath()` the components are suspended again and the loading ui is shown.

Comment: Wouldn't that apply to the entire page and not at a server component level? Also, what I'd like to do is to render a skeleton on the loading state (first render) and a spinner for the pending state (refetching after a mutation).

Comment: @Emi after looking into the docs again I don't see any way to do that on the component level, the answer posed above is the only solution I am afraid.

Comment: @Emi, for a component marked as `async`, loading.tsx will show a spinner. If this `async` component has in it's render function (the `return`) another `async` component wrapped with `<Suspense />` as well, it will show two spinners for the loading.tsx, and then for the suspense.

Comment: Fabio, loading.tsx wraps the layout.tsx and not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the official docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath

> revalidatePath only invalidates the cache when the included path is **next visited**. This means calling revalidatePath with a dynamic route segment will not immediately trigger many revalidations at once. The invalidation only happens when the path is next visited.

Thus, your question seems unclear. Please share your code and what exactly you want to do.

Probably you are looking for Server Action - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations. Specifically, you need to use something like `useFormState` from `react-dom`.

Also check out - https://youtu.be/dDpZfOQBMaU?si=jjWQlxq1zyO_h9hO&t=340

Example

```
"use client";

import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import { createTodo } from "@/app/actions";

const initialState = {
  message: "",
};

function SubmitButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <button type="submit" aria-disabled={pending}>
      Add
    </button>
  );
}

export function AddForm() {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(createTodo, initialState);

  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      <label htmlFor="todo">Enter Task</label>
      <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo" required />
      <SubmitButton />
      <p aria-live="polite" className="sr-only" role="status">
        {state?.message}
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Reference - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/next-forms/app/add-form.tsx

Comment: Does this address your question? You can use a client component to show spinner based on `useFormStatus`.

Comment: Also, you will see the fallback component only if the children have suspended or are in pending state. This does not seem to happen in your case, as server to server communication is very fast. Try slowing down your APIs from which the server component is fetching after rvalidation.

Comment: Hey bro, could you please let us know what you really need help with. Why are you wasting the bounty?